# Where and how do I put an inductor on a volume control

Tags: noise, inductor, high-frequency, ferrite, emi-filtering

I built an stereo equalizer but I made some mistakes. As the potentiometers didn't fit on my PCB I had to put them separated and make the connections with some wires. The other mistake is that I made a virtual ground instead of a real one.

This mistake causes the equalizer to amplify all the noise from all the mobile-phones sitting around in my house and makes a very annoying noise. It works fine when no phone is around (but this isn't the normal condition).

I bought some ferrite toroids to wind the wires around them. But I don't have enough for all the wires I have in here (they wouldn't fit in the case anyway). So some wires will have to share toroid.

Here is an example for how I think it could bee:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f97qsd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

So my big question in which direction should I turn the wires around the toroid?

I know I can turn one wire in any direction I like to if it's only one. If I put two wires around a ferrite toroid I have to care about the relation between these two wires (also easy). But when it comes with this case I don't know how to deal it.

Should I turn all in the same direction? or 2 in one direction and 1 in the other direction? or should I avoid one of them?

If someone could please explain what should I care about? I don't want just a make this or make that solution since this is something I can do on my own.

Comment: "So some wires will have to share toroid." WOAH WOAH, don't do that. You *don't* need any transformers.

Comment: If you have a DSO you could work on the frequencies of interest,without a response measuring device its just a blind mans game.

Comment: It could be that he's trying to make a common-mode choke...

Comment: @NickJohnson that's exactly what I want to make, sorry I didn't remember how this is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting ferrites around the circuit may actually make it worse, ie act as antennae. What you want to do is make the interconnections as short as possible and more importantly, put it all in a properly earthed metal box.

Comment: Yeah.  I'm minded of a fella (not me, but I worked with him) who put inductors on all the audio inputs and outputs of a device intended to be connected to a two-way radio.  There was no RF on the mic, but the mic pre-amp did dandy job of demodulating all the RF it got hold of.  Makes it kind of hard to talk to people when your mic amplifier craps out every time the transmitter goes on...

Comment: Ok, I'll look for a metal box.